# firewalld port forwarding not working in centOS

Tags: centos, firewalld

In the server machine i wanted to redirect all request come to 80 to 9000 port. so i have enabled the port and added port forwarding rule.

> firewall-cmd --permanent
> --add-forward-port=port=80:proto=tcp:toport=9000
>
> firewall-cmd --add-masquerade
>
> firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=9000/tcp
> firewall-cmd --permanent --add-port=80/tcp

All rule was added to default zone(trusted) as below.

```
  trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: 
  ports: 9000/tcp 9001/tcp 8080/tcp 80/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: port=80:proto=tcp:toport=9000:toaddr=
    port=8080:proto=tcp:toport=9001:toaddr=
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

But port forwarding not working. I have tested with as below.

> telnet < ip_address > 80

Response is Connection refused.

Answer (score 2):

You have set the permanent firewalld configuration, but you did not change the actual running configuration.

You should not use `--permanent` in any `firewall-cmd` commands, because you may lock yourself out of the system if you make a mistake. Instead,  you should execute the same command without `--permanent`, which causes it to take effect immediately but not persist, and then when you are sure the rules work properly, you can save them with `firewall-cmd --runtime-to-permanent`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Michael. Once i have apply the port forwarding rule, i have run the `firewall-cmd --reload`. So all changes got applied when list the rules.

Comment: May know to which zone, out side request comes? is it default zone?